# Deploying SpringBoot with H2 DB to Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, cloud, h2

I have relative simple question. If I choose to have a SpringBoot MVC application with an H2 Database as DBMS will I be possible to get it deployed at all to Heroku platform?

The reason I am asking this is because I know that there is no official support for a H2 Database plugin from Heroku, but may I still be able to run it and see basic Views ?

Have anyone tried this thing out and what are the consequences of such an action?

Very thankful for all feedback...

Answer (score 2):

**For the ones interested !**

I just wanted to share with you guys that I just recently pushed a local git repository with a SpringBoot application and H2 Database setting to the Heroku cloud and when I tried to access my application online throughout a given URL to test my REST API endpoint it just seemed to work perfectly fine.

Comment: But I hope you are aware that you cannot use an in memory database for production applications If you were to use it on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every 24 hours. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful information. I assume just like the article said that it shouldn't really be used in a production-environment since you then would need to upload the whole thing again, etc. 

Im working currently on an easier project at the moment so it wouldn't really be such a big deal anyway.